# How come Official Site of Apache HTTP Server is 'httpd.apache.org', if HTTPd is a runnable program?

Tags: html, apache, http, webserver, httpd.conf

I've done my research and everywhere it says HTTPd(HyperText Transfer Protocol daemon) is a program that runs in the background of a web server.

I was amazed & confused when I saw webpage- 'httpd.apache.org' for the 1st time in my life!!

Comment: The name of the daemon has nothing to do with DNS names pointing to its hosting machine.

Comment: HTTPD is the name of the Apache HTTP Server since ever, just that people usually call it Apache for historical reasons.

Comment: that's **https://**httpd.apache.org, the `httpd.` part is not the `protocol://` part, just that your browser is hiding the protocol part; a bad ergonomic change made years ago in the location bar of most browsers...

Comment: @regilero i love you jk tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's nothing more than a domain name.  Imagine my surprise finding a domain: http://internet.explorer.com/.

Comment: Can a normal person own a website with startup- 'httpd'? normal like me?

Comment: or like 'http' what's the difference?